# Is html sent compressed and/or minified?

Tags: html, jquery, compression, minify

I'm thinking about using the jQuery Ajax load method. In some cases, the html I want to load is quite large. I'm wondering if the browser already streamlines the process behind the scenes, or should I minify and/or compress the html before calling .load() from jQuery? If so, which one? or both? Is there a standard way to perform minification and/or compressing in this scenario?

### UPDATE

Does this make any sense:

The data I'm going to retrieve from the server is static. Let's say I have data for apples, oranges, kumquats, and papayas, and none of it changes "on the fly" (only when I update the site).

So is it preferable that I get the data as Json via jQuery this way:

```
$.getJson('kumquats')
```

(...and then, of course, process the results that come back)... OR ...simply send back the html with no need of massaging, as "kumquats" will always send back the exact same html, "oranges" will always be the same html, etc.

In the latter option, then, I would do something like this (jQuery pseudocode) instead:

```
$('#MainContent").html($.load("\Content\Kumquat.htm"));
```

In summation, I can send all the html fully-formed across the wire, and clog up the pipes with some extra bits for a bit, OR I can send a less verbose representation of the datta (json), and then massage it in the .getJson() callback function, transforming it into html. Performance-wise, does it make much difference? BTW, this is not "sensitive" data - it doesn't matter who sees it as it zips by through the ether.

Comment: That needs to happen on the server.

Comment: you can gzip the content on server-side...

Comment: Check your server settings for compression

Comment: Okay, if it's gzipped on the server, how does the client decompress it?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if the browser already streamlines the process behind the scenes

The browser can't control how much data the server sends in its response.

> or should I minify and/or compress the html before calling .load() from jQuery?

You call `load` on the client. The server has to do any minification or compression of the HTML.

> Is there a standard way to perform minification and/or compressing in this scenario?

Compression is usually handled by gzip encoding. How you set that up depends on your server and/or the server side programming language that is generating the content.

I'm not aware of any standard way to perform minification. I used HTML Tidy to do that once.

Comment: But the code we write is both client-side AND server-side, right? So the minification/compressing could/would be done in the server-side code. Or perhaps even separately, in cases where the html is static. The project/site type is Web Pages/Razor.

Answer (score 1):

The browser can't minify HTML before downloading it first.  The only reason you want to minify is to reduce download time by decreasing the file size of the download, so this is counter intuitive.

Your server needs to minify and/or compress.  It probably already is compressing by default (`mod_deflate` on apache for example).  Minification of  the HTML can be done in a variety of ways depending upon the server-side technology you are using.  There may be a library for it, or you could use a third party CDN to minify and serve the content for you.

Comment: It's my own html that I want to minify/compress. The jQuery .load() will retrieve an html file on the server that is part of my project/site.